# Magento 2: Product name scope

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I've successfully migrated a complete magento 1.9 database with 900 products to a 2.2.6 using the data migration tool.

Now I wonder how to change the product name scope from global to store view. We need each product to have it's own name on each view.

As you can see, it's actually set to global and if I change it on one store the changes are applied to the other views. That's not the behavior that we need.
[image: Magento 2 Product Name Scope]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to Stores -> Attributes -> Product.
Then find your attribute and in it's edit form in Properties tab change scope from Global to Store view.

Comment: Wow thank you, I didn't know the Migration tool actually created a new set of attributes where the scope has been set to Global. Thank you!